# Как расположить элементы по центру таблицы в dearpygui?

Tags: python, dearpygui

Есть такой код:

```
with dpg.table(tag='bor', parent='main_wind'):
    dpg.add_table_column()
    dpg.add_table_column()
    dpg.add_table_column()
    with dpg.table_row():
        dpg.add_button(label='EMPTY', tag='0')
        dpg.add_button(label='EMPTY1', tag='1')
        dpg.add_button(label='EMPTY2', tag='2')
```

Хочу расположить кнопки по центру ячеек, но они смещаются влево. Как это сделать? В демке `show_demo()` почему-то не нашёл такого примера. Сортировка, рамки - всё что угодно есть, кроме того, что мне нужно. Заранее спасибо